# Is there any verse that talks about bad human births?

Tags: karma, sin, birth

> Now after having suffered the torments inflicted in the hells, the evil-doers pass into animal bodies. 2. Criminals in the highest degree enter the bodies of all plants successively. 3. Mortal sinners enter the bodies of worms or insects. 4. Minor offenders enter the bodies of birds. 5. Criminals in the fourth degree enter the bodies of aquatic animals. 6. Those who have committed a crime effecting loss of caste, enter the bodies of amphibious animals. 7. Those who have committed a crime degrading to a mixed caste, enter the bodies of deer. 8. Those who have committed a crime rendering them unworthy to receive alms, enter the bodies of cattle.
> (**Vishnu Smriti XLIV**)

> But those who do not follow either of these two paths are born among small animals and insects again and again. [This can be said about those who are born in] this third state: ‘Be born and die.’ This is why the other world does not get filled up. Therefore one should despise this state. Here is a verse on the subject—[(Chandogya-Upanishad Verse 5.10.8)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239197.html)

So if you do bad karma you will be born as an animal and insects.

But is there any verse that tell us about human birth but with diseases, abnormality and disorders[*Congenital disorder*] . 
Disorders that we inherent by our parents.

Comment: we don't inherit anything but our own karma. Garuda Puran tells us that after taking birth as animals/plants, we are born as diseased/disabled humans with some remaining bad karma. similarly on other end, after taking birth as deva, we are born as pious/rich humans with some remaining good karma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we have such verses.

For example from Manu Smriti:

> 11.51. A stealer of (cooked) food, dyspepsia; a stealer of the words (of the Veda), dumbness a stealer of clothes, white leprosy; a
> horse-stealer, lameness.
>
> 11.51a. The stealer of a lamp will become blind; he who extinguishes it will become one-eyed; injury (to sentient beings) is punished by
> general sickliness; an adulterer (will have) swellings (in his limbs).
>
> 11.52. Thus in consequence of a remnant of (the guilt of former) crimes, are born idiots, dumb, blind, deaf, and deformed men, who are
> (all) despised by the virtuous.

And there are other scriptures too having similar verses. Deformities, disabilities, diseases etc. are all signs of sins from previous births.

Comment: Thanks but can you give some verses from upanishad or vedas

Comment: Okay I'll try but I'm not sure if it's possible@DarkKnight

Comment: @DarkKnight - that's like asking for prose inside a poem. different parts of scriptures deal with different things. besides, most veda shakas are lost in time.

Comment: @mar since Smriti are derived from the vedas, vedas should contain some verses like this.

Comment: @DarkKnight - if Vedas already contain those verses, what is the need to 'DERIVE' Smritis from it ?